# Index Management Magento 2

Tags: index, management

What does it take to fix these errors?

[image]

Comment: let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: You website has a lot of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@rakesh is right

go  to command line and fire below commands

```
cd yourmagento directory 

php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

after this commands refresh your magento cache.

Answer (score 0):

you have to run command,

```
   php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Comment: Still the same way